# Get selection\manipulate a field of "Non-Connected" relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to `select` or `manipulate` a field and I'm probably doing something wrong.
That's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Record1ID
    ,Record1IdName
    ,Record2Id
    ,Record2IdName
    ,TmpTable.is_child
    ,TmpTable.is_child_parent
FROM db777..Connection Child
INNER JOIN db777..Contact cont ON Child.Record2Id = cont.ContactId
INNER JOIN db666..idt_v_sales TmpTable ON cont.Id = TmpTable.Id
WHERE (
        Child.Record2RoleId = 'F07533'
        OR Child.Record1RoleId = 'C417DE'
        )
ORDER BY Child.Record2Id;
```

The `Connection` table has two important columns. First one is the `Record1Id`(Parent Id) and the second one in `Record2Id`(Child Id).
I have decided that the `Record2Id` will "lead" in terms of `Join` between the tables, but, When I want to have the correct data\ manipulating the data of the field `TmpTable.is_child_parent` I'm actually getting the wrong result for that field since my primary key was the Child's key when making the `Join(s)` and that field is a `parent` field.
So, how can I fix that in order to use and get both Parent's and Child's data?

My desired result is as follow:

```html
Record1Id  Record1IdName  Record2Id  Record2IdName  TmpTable.is_child TmpTable.is_parent_child
  123          A       111     DD        40               50
  456          B       111     DD        40               0
```

`Connection` table contains the Foloowing columns:
`Record1Id` ,`Record1IdName` ,`Record2Id` ,`Record2IdName`.

`Contact` table contains 'ContactId' column which can be either Parent's Id(Record1Id from Connection table) or Child's Id(Record2Id from connection table).

`TmpTable`(idt_v_sales) contains a different type of Id which makes the connection to Contact table in addition to the requested columns: `is_child` and `is_parent_child`. As mentioned above, `is_child` is an `integer` only the child can have while `is_parent_child` is an integer only the parent can have.

Comment: Kindly share sample data for all tables and your desired output.

Comment: Kindly also share sample data for all tables from which you require the shared desired output.